# How to set up CAN device with C using iplink

Tags: c, linux, can-bus, ipconfig

I would like to programmatically set a CAN device through C.

I can do this using IP Link through the terminal with:

```
    ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000
```

How can I achieve this using C

I've looked around the iplink code on GitHub but I can't seem to work it out.

Could you please send me in the right direction or even provide an example? I am far from fluent in C

Comment: *"How can I achieve this using C... I am far from fluent in C"* - You should probably use a language you are more familiar with. I'm guessing it is going to be a painful experience for you.

Comment: (Usually) a CAN link requires appropriate hardware at each end of the link.  Does your hardware include a CAN interface?  Which specific hardware are you using?